# Command prompt ren wildcard *

Tags: cmd.exe

I have a bunch of files which look like this:

[image: File List - Screenshot].

I want to remove all "IMG_20190718_". Why does `ren IMG_20190718_* *` not work and how do I make it work?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. When you ask a question, please put the information as text, and not as a picture. Also, you might do some preliminary research before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `/` to delete a prefix. For example: if I have the following files

```
18-07-2020  17:18                 6 IMG_20_14.png
18-07-2020  17:18                 6 IMG_20_15.png
18-07-2020  17:18                 6 IMG_20_16.png
```

I can use:

```
ren "IMG_20_*.png" "///////*.png"
```

which has as result:

```
18-07-2020  17:18                 6 14.png
18-07-2020  17:18                 6 15.png
18-07-2020  17:18                 6 16.png
```